# I'm using C# Visual Studio forms. How do I get a var in Program.cs to a VS form?

Tags: c#, forms, visual-studio

I'm using C# Visual Studio forms. I have a var in Program.cs and don't know how to get that var to the form.

In Program.cs

```
if (jsonString1.Contains("success") == true)
            {
                var js2 = "Success!";
```

in Form1.cs

```
private void Message_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            textmessage.Text = js2.ToString();
        }
```

[image]
[image: This is the code that creates the var]

[image: When I hover over the var in Form1 it shows that on the form]
[image: When I click the form button I get this exception]

Comment: Sorry no idea why the picture are not showing up.

Comment: It would be good to take a few minutes to cover the basics. This relates to variables (and scoping). https://csharp.net-tutorials.com/basics/variables/ , https://codebuns.com/csharp-basics/variables/ - in this case, you'll want to also read up about *fields* and *members*. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/fields

Comment: Is this _Windows Forms_? There is no "Visual Studio Forms. It's not clear from your code and pictures (no pictures of code please) what/why you have that string in Program.cs. But, if you want to pass it to the form, add a string parameter to the form's constructor, or add a public string property to the Form's class and set it after constructing the form (and before calling `Run`

Comment: Thanks Flydog57. I am creating the forms within VS so if VS creates windows forms then yes. I think you would need to click the links to see my screenshots, when I submitted this question they said I can't embed the pics until I had 10 points. I'll read up on that.

Comment: Thanks user286 for the links, I'll check them out. I'm just not sure what the search would be to get what I need. When I hover over the var in Form1.cs the var comes through but when I click the button I get a null exception.

Comment: Olivier I am restricted on how I could ask this question because I don't have enough points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is you need to define the var as Class property

in Form1.cs

```
public string js2 {get; set;}
private void Message_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        textmessage.Text = js2.ToString();
    }
```

In Program.cs

```
var form = new Form1();
....
if (jsonString1.Contains("success") == true)
        {
            form.js2 = "Success!";
```